# The billing and shipping address in Email template to be clear | Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, email

We need the address of both billing & shipping to be clear in the email template of orders. We are using Magento.

**city:** billing city,

**region:** billing Region,

**Street:** Billing Street

I need to add the word city, region, street before each of them to make it clear in the order notification emails.

Please help us to do it..

Answer (score 2):

In Magento configuration path **Customer >> Customer Configurations >> Address Templates** You can update the default template for **HTML** with:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}Company: {{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}Address 1: {{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}Address 2: {{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}City: {{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}Postcode: {{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

**Note:** This will reflect all areas where magento use this template to display the customer address

Also if you want to add the translation, switch the configuration scope to  corresponding store view and then make the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I found the answer to my question that i was searching for it:

If you need to display the shipping or billing address in Order email notification You can use the following:

**For Billing:**

City:  {{var order.getBillingAddress().getCity()}},
Region:  {{var order.getBillingAddress().getRegion()}},
Street1:  {{var order.getBillingAddress().getStreet1()}}
Street2: {{var order.getBillingAddress().getStreet2()}},
Company:  {{var order.getBillingAddress().getCompany()}},
Zip code:{{var order.getBillingAddress().getPostcode()}}

**For Shipping**

City:    {{var order.getShippingAddress().getCity()}},
Region:  {{var order.getShippingAddress().getRegion()}},
Street1: {{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet1()}}
Street2: {{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet2()}},
Company: {{var order.getShippingAddress().getCompany()}},
Zip code:{{var order.getShippingAddress().getPostcode()}}

Thanks,